# Passenger + nginx + Rails4 : 'Further configuration is required' (nginx's default page is shown) instead of my rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, passenger

I've installed Passenger with nginx on my ubuntu (12.04) server. Everything seems to be working perfectly fine (i.e. nginx is firing up w/o any issues) except that on the browser I'm shown the default nginx landing page *("Welcome to nginx! If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and working. Further configuration is required."*) I was expecting my rails app's home page on the browser.

Following is my nginx.conf:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;
events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # nginx-naxsi config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-naxsi
    ##

    # include /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;

    ##
    # Phusion Passenger config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed passenger or passenger-enterprise
    ##

    passenger_root /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini;
    #passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;
    passenger_ruby /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby;


    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name mydomain.com;
        root /path_from_root_to/my_app/public;
        passenger_enabled on;
        rails_env production;
    }   


    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


# mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
# }
```

Comment: Restarted the server after configuration?

Comment: yes I did.. sudo service nginx stop and sudo service nginx start

Comment: Are you specifying the absolute path to your application's public directory. like `/var/www/rails_app/public`?

Comment: Yes I am. The complete (absolute) path from server's root to my app's public folder (/root_folder/some_folder/my_app/public;). I dont need to run rails (rails s) separately right? Just running nginx should suffice right?

Comment: Yes, you don't need to run it separately.

Comment: Did you resolve? Are you routing www.domain.com, and domain.com? Could it be a mismatch?

Comment: Not yet Damien :( But after much reconfiguring the browser showed this error  `cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in 'require' /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in 'require'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:245:in `block in run_load_path_setup_code'`